# Aspx and connecting to a access database on a share

Tags: asp.net, ms-access

Im trying to make a aspx application that connects to a access database on a share.
the path is correct, when i copy paste it in a run screen it opens a database right away.

The weird thing is that the exception that im getting is this, however the database is not a mdb and not in that location either.(it was dutch I translated it, might not be 100% correct translation):

> Cant find file C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\dbo.mdb

This is my code:
The exception is fired on the ExecuteReader

```
namespace AssetDB
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void btn_zoek_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txt_name.Text.Length < 4)
                return;

            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\\netwerk\data\TeamFolders\ICT\Asset Database\_Backend\Assets_be.accdb; "))
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "Select * from dbo.Bruikleen_Laptops where Laptop_id = @id";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", txt_name.Text);
                conn.Open();
                using (OleDbDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                while(r.Read())
                {
                    drop_gevonden.Items.Add(r["Laptop_id"].ToString());
                }
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe there's something else in your code trying to connect to that location? But...why are you using access as the backend to a web app? It's really not suited to it. It's slow (especially on a share),  has difficulty when the size of the data gets large and has problems with concurrent usage by multiple users. There are so many databases around (even with free versions) you could use (SQL Express, MySQL etc) which would be much more efficient, secure and reliable.

Comment: This is the only code on the page, im trying out to connect to it, i personally never connected to access DB's before.. and yes, I'd much rather use MSSQLServer myself.. But im limited by the person who made the database

Comment: there are tools to migrate from Access to SQL, I think the process is not very difficult these days. Anyway, just because the code on the page isn't calling this other file, doesn't mean there isn't some code elsewhere in the pipeline that's being executed - e.g. in global.asax or in a master page, a HTTP module, a class that the page inherits, some code called from this page. There are lots of places. Also, your sample isn't the "only code on the page" because you haven't shown the Page_Load method etc.

Comment: Editted, now there is everything

Comment: hm. Have you done a Find on the rest of your solution to see if there are any other references to dbo.mdb? Also, that file is not some dependency of the main access file, is it? e.g. if the database was split? I notice your file is called Assets_be - the convention is to use _be for the backend database.

Comment: This is indeed only the backend, it has the tables in it. There is also a front end, which has the forms that are used by users to input data.  Searched the entire solution, it couldnt find a reference to dbo.mdb

Comment: And is the front-end called dbo.mdb? Alternatively, did you come across anything by doing a Find across the whole .NET solution?

Comment: If i change my select query to: "Select * from Bruikleen_Laptops where Laptop_id = @id"  it will only tell me it cannot find the input table or query "Bruikleen_Laptops"

Comment: Front end is called Assets.accdb

Comment: ah...of course. You've figured it yourself. I hadn't noticed because I'm so used to SQL Server. "dbo" would be the schema in SQL Server that the table belongs to, but Access/OLE has no such concept, so it thinks you're trying to look for another DB file. Now if it can't find your table...that's a different problem, maybe just check the name is valid. I'm not sure if there are any security restrictions that could be in the way.

Comment: ARGGGHH  nevermind, i found it......  tables in access are called dbo_ not dbo.  Thanks for the brainstorming..

Comment: they don't have to be as far as I know. That's just your colleague's naming convention. Admittedly it's a long time since I worked with Access (pre .accdb!) Glad you found it though, sorry I wasn't more help.